# MySQL Processlist Seems to Show Incorrect User When Running a Custom Function

Tags: mysql

I am on MySQL 8.0.28 and I have this function:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE FUNCTION DelayedHello()
RETURNS VARCHAR(20)
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DO SLEEP(3);
  RETURN CONCAT('Hello ', 'World!');
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And this was created by the root user.

But when a user called `test` runs this function, in the `show processlist`, this is what I see. So, it looks like the user `root` is running it.

```
127.0.0.1> select * from information_schema.processlist ;
+-------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| ID    | USER            | HOST             | DB        | COMMAND | TIME    | STATE                  | INFO                                         |
+-------+-----------------+------------------+-----------+---------+---------+------------------------+----------------------------------------------+
| 48547 | root            | %:40814          | helpscout | Query   | 1       | User sleep             | DO SLEEP(3)                                  |
```

I tried to query the `information_schema.processlist` to see the user but it returned the same info that the user root seems to be executing this. So, is there a way to show in the processlist that it was the `test` who is running this? If not, how do I find out who actually called this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a combination of the `DEFINER`, the `INVOKER`, and the [default behavior around both of these concepts](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/stored-objects-security.html) when the function is created or altered.

When you create a function, it captures the `CURRENT_USER()` as the `DEFINER` unless you explicitly state one. In your example, this defaulted to the `root` user.

When your function is called, a security check is performed to provide context for execution. Since your function had a `DEFINER` of `root`, querying both `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist` would return the calling user as `root` even though `test` was calling it.

If you alter the function to what I have below, it should capture the `CURRENT_USER()` (e.g. `root` or the creator) as the `DEFINER` because of the `DEFINER=CURRENT_USER()` syntax.

When the function below is called, querying `SHOW PROCESSLIST` or `SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist;` would show the function as being executed by the `INVOKER` - in this case `test` because the `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` syntax is specified.

```
USE YourDatabase;
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `YourDatabase`.`DelayedHello`;

DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=CURRENT_USER() FUNCTION `DelayedHello`() RETURNS varchar(20)
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DO SLEEP(30);
    RETURN CONCAT('Hello ','World!');
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Keep in mind that:

- Using `SQL SECURITY DEFINER` means that the function will be executed and reported as the `DEFINER` **and with the permissions available to the `DEFINER`.**
- Using `SQL SECURITY INVOKER` means **your function will be executed  with the permissions of the `INVOKER`** and reported as the `INVOKER` when examining processes.

Edit: Cleaned up some of the example code and explanations.

Comment: Thank you! This is a great explanation!